# What should I do, if my information has been compromised in the Apollo breach?

Tags: privacy

I received a message from haveibeenpwned.com that some of my information has been compromised.

[image: Description of the attack]

The link in the screenshot below refers to [this article](https://www.wired.com/story/apollo-breach-linkedin-salesforce-data/).

What should I do as a response to this?

I don't remember whether or not I ever entered any information into this Apollo service (I don't even remember that I ever used it). I assume that they somehow harvested my data from other sources (e. g. social networks). I use different passwords for different web sites and I don't know which passwords were compromised. Changing **all** passwords is not an option (there are too many of them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apollo is not a service you would have directly interacted with.  They sift through public information on the internet (twitter, company websites, linked in, etc.) to collect contact information, such as names and emails.  They essentially gathered massive amounts of data which businesses would then pay them for in order to find sales leads.

You don't have any passwords that need to be changed, because no passwords were exposed.  The only real danger is that all this public information is gathered together in a single place, which makes it easier for scammers (phone or phishing) to fool you into falling for their scams.

Just stay skeptical of offers that are too good to be true.  Be wary of anyone who is trying to scare you into making a quick decision.  I'm not saying be paranoid, but be aware.